# How to copy a line from a text file and print the line and line number

Tags: java, string, exception, int, stringtokenizer

I am having trouble making a program that would find an error in a text file and print the line where the error is and also print the line number the error is on. The error that it is looking for is if there is 6 words/ numbers on each line if not there would be an error

For Example:

text File

name breed month day year weight

name breed month

name breed month day year weight

***Error lines in file:

name breed month
Error on line #2: number of fields should be 6, not 3.***

```
int numline= 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

    // read a line from the input file via sc into line
        line = sc.nextLine();




        try{
        StringTokenizer stk = new StringTokenizer(line);
        String name = stk.nextToken();
        String breed = stk.nextToken();
        int month = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        int day = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        int year = Integer.parseInt(stk.nextToken());
        double weight = Double.parseDouble(stk.nextToken());
        numline++;
        Dog list = new Dog(name, breed, month, day, year, weight);


        dogs.add(list);




        }

        catch(Exception missError)
        {
            System.out.println("Error Lines detected in file:");
            System.out.println("Number of fields on line must be 6");

        }

    }
     // close the file
sc.close();
  System.out.println(numline);
```

Comment: place `numLine++` as the first line in your `try` block and use that in `catch` bolck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place `numLine++` as the first line in your `try` block and use that in `catch` block. Also use `line.split("\\s+");` which returns `String[]`, with that you will know the no of fields before hand, then you don't need to depend on an `Exception`.

```
int numLine= 0;
while(sc.hasNextLine())
    {

        line = sc.nextLine();
        numLine++
        String[] fields = line.split("\\s+");
        if(fields.length != 6) {
           System.out.println("Error Line number:"+numLine);
           System.out.println("Number of fields on line must be 6, but it has :"+ fields.length);
        }
     }
```

Comment: Thanks, How would I print the line and the line number.

Comment: It is counting the amount of characters in each line not words.

Comment: This is the outcome:   Error Line number:1
Number of fields on line must be 6, but it has :27